# Chrome devtools DOM mutation events on page-reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging?hl=ptVitor#breakpoints-mutation-events) you can set breakpoints on DOM mutation by right click on the element and select "Break on..." > Subtree modifications.

This works really well bu
I would like to set the breakpoint, then reload the page and watch for DOM modifications and then hit the breakpoint. The breakpoint doesnt seem to "stuck". This might be impossible, I dont know.

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint on another script what run early. After this breakpoint fired you can set DOM breakpoint and let go the previous breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In your page's markup, place this `<script>` tag:

```
<script>debugger</script>
```

It will trigger a breakpoint when the DOM parser gets to that point. This will enable you to place a new breakpoint on whatever event you want of the element. And, because you stopped it soon, it will (most likely) be before the event you're interested in has happened.